# ESP32-WROOM - Problem using multiple cores

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am having issues with my code for an ESP32 Wroom.
I am trying to use both cores on the esp to speed up and create an efficient process for the device; one core checks for a change/response from a website page. and the other changes the led patterns according to the response received.

Core 0 (getting response) should be constantly updating a string called "payload" with the latest received information form the website. this is happening whilst the other core is displaying a pattern until it receives a change in "payload"; and changes accordingly.

the issue i am having is that the esp after uploading and first time starting prints the following message every 1-2 seconds:

```
rst:0x8 (TG1WDT_SYS_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4 
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044 
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5816
entry 0x400806ac
```

This is also printed in some of the messages:

> Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Double exception)

I am new to ESP32's and have not much experience with Arduino, does anybody know what I am doing wrong or ways of achieving the same aim avoiding the current issues. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for my project.

```
TaskHandle_t Task1;

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 50
#define PIN 27

uint8_t hue[NUM_LEDS];
CRGBArray<NUM_LEDS> leds;

const char* ssid     = "Username";
const char* password = "Password";

const char* serverName = "https://example.com/page.php";

String apiKeyValue = "tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";
String payload;

void codeForTask1( void * parameter )
{
  for (;;) 
  {   
    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      HTTPClient http;
      
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(serverName);
      
      // Specify content-type header
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      
      // Prepare your HTTP POST request data
      String httpRequestData = "api_key=" + apiKeyValue;
      
    
      // Send HTTP POST request
      int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
      
          
      if (httpResponseCode>0)
      {
        payload = http.getString();
      }
    }
    delay(1000);    
  }
}

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(500);
  }
  
  
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
  {
    hue[i] = 255 / NUM_LEDS * i;
  }
  
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    &codeForTask1,
    "led1Task",
    2000,
    NULL,
    1,
    &Task1,
    0);
  delay(500);  // needed to start-up task1
}

void loop() 
{
  String payload2 = payload;
  if(payload2.indexOf("rainbow") >= 0)
  {
    while(payload2.indexOf("rainbow") >= 0)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++)
      {
        leds[i] = CHSV(hue[i]++, 255, 255);
      }            
      delay(100);
      FastLED.show();  
    }
    Serial.print(payload2 + " || Rainbow \n");
  }
  else if(payload2.indexOf("worm") >= 0)
  {
    
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++)
    {
        for(int e=0; e<=1; e++)
        {
          if(e == 0){
            leds[i] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
            leds[i+2] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
            leds[i+4] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
            leds[i+6] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
            FastLED.show();
          }else{
            leds[i] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
            leds[i+2] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
            FastLED.show();
          }
          delay(100);
        }
    }      
    Serial.print(payload2 + " || Worm \n");
  }
  else if(payload2.indexOf("ant") >= 0)
  {
    
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++)     // loop
    {    
      for(int e=0; e<=1; e++)
      {
        if(e == 0)
        {
          leds[i] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
          leds[i+1] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
          leds[i+2] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
          leds[i+4] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
          leds[i+5] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
          leds[i+3] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  
          FastLED.show();
        }
        else
        {
          leds[i] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
          leds[i+1] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
          FastLED.show();
        }
        delay(50);
      }
    }
    Serial.print(payload2 + " || Ant \n");
  }
  else if(payload.indexOf("off") >= 0)
  {
    Serial.print(payload2 + " || Off \n" );
  }
  else if(!payload2.isEmpty())
  {
    String dab = payload;
    String hexstring = dab;
    long number = (long) strtol( &hexstring[0], NULL, 16 );
    int r = number >> 16;
    int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
    int b = number & 0xFF;
    
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++){
      leds[i] = CRGB(r, g, b);
    }
    FastLED.show();               // start new rgb led strip assignment/patterns
    Serial.print(payload2 + " || CUSTOM COLOR \n");
  } 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Task 1: Done \n");
}
```

Comment: Both tasks seem to be accessing your `payload` variable - maybe try putting a mutex around accesses.

Comment: @kynan . I am also facing this issue. did you get the solution for the above issue? please share it. if you found the issue and solution